# Versioning git repo inside other git repo

Tags: git

I am working on developing a little piece of software that works with git repositories, and I would like to be able to write some tests. In order to do so, I created a `test-repo` folder inside my project that itself is a git repository. In my tests I reference that repository to ensure that the commands I run against a repository in precisely known state.

My question is: Can I version that nested repo as part of the main repo of the project? Please note this is not really the same problem that submodules solve: The nested repo is really part of the enclosing project, not an externally referenced piece of software.

Comment: Why don't you build the test repository with a script before running the tests?

Comment: @tewe I could do that but that would be a bit painful as I would need to replay edition of a file. Faster and simpler to keep the repository around.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I tried to add the .git directory using `-f` force flag. I do not want submodule as this is not really the use case for an external repository. Of course, I could do that but this would mean keeping track of 2 repos, one being very small only for testing purpose. Not practical and defeats the purpose of versioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that git detects its own `.git` files and doesn't allow to work with them. If you however rename your test repo's `.git` folder to something different, e.g. `_git` it will work. Only one thing you need to do is to use GIT_DIR variable or `--git-dir` command line argument in your tests to specify the folder.

Comment: Problem is I am using a thirdparty library that hides this information (`--git-dir` is a flag that needs to be passed as option to git itself, not the command). But this gives me an idea: rename the directory to commit, then renaming the other way around before testing. But it is anyway cumbersome. Think I will try to hook into the underlying library and set git-dir.

Comment: @insitu Is `GIT_DIR` environment variable not available too?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Well, it could be but this would also imply hacking the lib I am using. Seems much simpler to hack it once in order to be able to provide path to repo.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not an "externally referenced piece of software", [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) are still a good approach, in that it helps to capture known state of repositories.

I would rather put both `repo` and `test-repo` within a parent repo "`project`":

```
project
  repo
  rest-repo
```

That way, I can record the exact SHA1 of both `repo` and `test-repo`.